# Merge SQL database values when items have same value in specified column

Tags: php, sql, database, charts, group-by

I know how to solve this in a non-elegant, non-practical way, meaning sending requests, one by one, for each value in specified column that is shared and then handle all data from that specific output, then, do the same for another value, etc., etc. But I was wondering if someone out there thought of an ELEGANT and PRACTICAL way, which would mean all this is handled by one single PHP function.

Basically, I have this table:

```
  location  |   title   | description | quantity 
============|===========|=============|==========
  shelf     |   apple   |    red      |    2
  drawer    |   banana  |    yellow   |    4
  shelf     |   kiwi    |    green    |    2
  cupboard  |   lemon   |    yellow   |    1
  fridge    |   melon   |    orange   |    3
  drawer    |   peach   |    orange   |    1
```

And what I eventually want is to create a jQuery pie chart that tells me what percentage of `title` is in each `location`. But before that I need a function that outputs `shelf => 4` (2+2), `drawer => 5` (4+1), etc., etc.

So, the question is, is there an elegant, practical way to make this happen? Meaning, to retrieve all rows but group together all data by location and, then, sum each location's quantity to be later on turned into a percentage for the pie chart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select location, sum (quantity) as sum_quantity from table group by location;
```

and later using `$rows` as result from query above,

```
function prepareForChart ($rows) {

  $ret = array();
  $total = 0;
  foreach ($rows as $el) $total += $el["sum_quantity"];

  foreach ($rows as $el) {
    $ret[] = array(
      $el["location"] => $el["sum_quantity"],
      "percentage"    => 100 * $el["sum_quantity"]/$total,
    );
  }

  return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Hey! You even did my work with the turning-into-percentage function! Thanks! Anyway, what does that `SELECT` string output? Because I'm handling my queries by passing them through an array-building function; however, in this case I'm getting that bothersome `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given...` error.

Comment: @QuestionerNo27 query returns unique locations with summed quantities per location, so that is only two columns.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT location, SUM(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM table 
GROUP BY location
```